# Python Speech Recognition how to extract only main transcript with show_all enabled

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech, google-speech-api

I'm trying to learn speech recognition for a program I'm making. I'm currently having it contentiously listen and display what I say.

```
def record():
    repeat = True
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        while repeat:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            user = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-US', show_all = True)
            print(str(user))
```

The code works, but at times when it doesn't understand me or I make a sound effect (cough or sneeze) It outputs with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 57, in <module>
    record()
  File "main.py", line 24, in record
    user = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-US')
  File "C:\Users\vorte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

I fixed this by changing `user = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-US')` to `user = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-US', show_all = True)`

But the problem now is I get a tuple, list, dictionary mixed string with unnecessary information that displays what it thinks I said + all the alternatives.

```
{'alternative': [{'transcript': 'Sun even working anymore', 'confidence': 0.88974512}, {'transcript': 'son even working anymore'}, {'transcript': 'some even working anymore'}, {'transcript': 'send even working anymore'}, {'transcript': 'Saint even working anymore'}], 'final': True}
```

My question is if there is any way I could pull or receive the transcript with the highest confidence while the show_all is enabled, because if I turn it off it will bring up errors again.

Comment: I know it may require a little extra effort but why not use `user['alternative'][0]['transcript']` if user isn't an empty list?

Comment: @SergioR I would need to make a load of following changes with that. I decided to just skip showing the output because I don't really need it. I'm making a Zoom bot that auto joins your classes for you and it basically listens to the teacher and if the teacher says like my name or mentions the word test or quiz I get a notification on my phone.So all i had to do was see if those words were in my string.

Comment: It seems as if you don't have any exception handler which then instantly exits the program. If you want it to loop, you would have to do a `whileTrue`. Would you mind providing more details on your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that:

```
def record():

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        try:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            user = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-US')
            print(str(user))
        except:
            record()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(str(['alternative'][0]['transcript']user)
```

You can use this code, it work